# left merge df2 onto df1 using id and date, but also porting over all id in df2 in df1

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, `df1, df2`. `df1` has columns `id, dt, date`. `df2` has columns `id, date`. I want to do the following merge:

```
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['id', 'date'], how='left')
```

however, I also want to make sure that for every `dt` in `df1`, it has all the `df2.id.unique()` and if it doesn't, i want to insert the corresponding `id` rows.

Is there a way to achieve this behavior using `merge`?

## Example

```
# Note that dt and date are python datetime and date, resp. but for this example, we don't need to be concerned with that so i will use ints
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
  "id": [1, 2, 1, 2],
  "dt": [10.1, 10.1, 11.1, 11.1],
  "date": [10, 10, 11, 11]
})

# id = 3 doesn't exist in df1
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
  "id": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
  "date": [10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11],
  "some_other_col": [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6]
})

# After the merge I want to have:
merged = pd.DataFrame({
  "id": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
  "dt": [10.1, 10.1, 10.1, 11.1, 11.1, 11.1],
  "date": [10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11],
  "some_other_col": [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6]
})
```

Comment: After your merge, run a `.loc`: ```merged.loc[merged.dt.isna(), 'dt']=df1.dt.unique()```

Comment: @sammywemmy do you mean after doing `pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['id', 'date'], how='left')`?

Comment: @sammywemmy if so, then no `merged.dt` is `na`

Comment: it should be how='outer'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one option is to call `.loc` after your merge:

```py
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['id', 'date'], how='outer')
merged.loc[merged.dt.isna(), 'dt']=df1.dt.unique()
merged
   id    dt  date  some_other_col
0   1  10.1    10             1.1
1   2  10.1    10             1.2
2   1  11.1    11             1.4
3   2  11.1    11             1.5
4   3  10.1    10             1.3
5   3  11.1    11             1.6
```

Another option would be to introduce the missing rows into df1, before merging. This uses the [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
(df1
.complete({'id':df2.id.unique()}, ('dt', 'date'))
.merge(df2, on=['id','date'],how='left')
)
   id    dt  date  some_other_col
0   1  10.1    10             1.1
1   1  11.1    11             1.4
2   2  10.1    10             1.2
3   2  11.1    11             1.5
4   3  10.1    10             1.3
5   3  11.1    11             1.6
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `merged.loc[merged.dt.isna(), 'dt']=df1.dt.unique()` won't work if you have more than one missing row. The second approach seems more robust.

Comment: @roulette01 kindly test the options to see which one is more appropriate for your use case